# How to execute new insert/update trigger on existing rows in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I have added a insert/update trigger to a table that already has some rows.
What is the cleanest way to execute the new insert/update trigger on the existing rows?

(Dirty idea is to modify some column and revert it in a transaction. Or add temporarily a column a change its data.)

Comment: Triggers do not work on existing rows unlees something changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run an update statement that resembles what's in the trigger, without the join to `inserted`. If you show the code in your trigger, we can help you more specifically.

Also, if you can explain why a no-up update wouldn't still fire the trigger, that would be great. If you currently check for actual changes in values, you could always alter the trigger temporarily to not bother doing that check.

Comment: There are multiple more complex triggers. So there is no function / workaround to force run the triggers? (The no-up update did not seem to fire the trigger.)

Comment: You'll need to post more details if you want help. We can't fix a trigger that we can't see and that "did not seem to fire."

Comment: Thanks for hint. I found a strange condition in the trigger, that checked that `inserted` has only one row. So, that's why the no-up update on whole table was not working:(